# Trying to use df.loc to make a small dataframe but I'm getting an error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently working on a function that takes a dataframe as an argument and I'm trying to get two specific rows to return with two certain columns.

The rows I'm trying to get are indexed at 112 and 180.

The columns I'm trying to get are titled `Sex` and `Total`.

So far I've been able to get the rows 112 THROUGH 180 for these two columns but not the two columns alone.

Here's what I currently have in my program:

`data.loc[112:180, ['Sex', 'Total']]` because when I use `data.loc[112, 180, ['Sex', 'Total']]` it says I'm giving it too many indexes.

Any help?

Comment: try: `data.loc[[112, 180], ['Sex', 'Total']]`

Comment: @nick Bless tf up. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `112:180`.

indexing with `112:180` will give you all the rows in between these rows.

If you want only those two specific rows,do:

```
data.loc[[112, 180], ['Sex', 'Total']]
```

Comment: Yeah, I was struggling with the second brackets. I didn't know I should have been adding them. Thank you!